# POSTMAN Error - Could not get any response

Tags: laravel, api, xampp, postman

I have a VPS Server where I installed Laravel-5.8 for the backend. Also, I installed XAMPP and made the Laravel Application to be on Port 8888. The VPS server is 10.10.10.7(not the real IP). On the VPS server, I tried to test using POSTMAN:

> http://10.10.10.7:8888/backend/api/login
>
> http://localhost:8888/backend/api/login

Both work perfectly on the server. However, when I tried to test using POSTMAN from an external system with:

> http://10.10.10.7:8888/backend/api/login

I got this error:

[image: postman error]

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Surely your firewall, check your IP table rules and check on Google this kind of problem

Comment: The answer is in your question `The VPS server is 10.10.10.7(not the real IP)`. You need to use the external IP of your server to reach your site (given that its properly configured by apache/xampp)

Comment: @Vincent Decaux - Problem Solved. As you advised, I went to the server Firewall inbound and allowed 8888.  Thanks